# Disable the F5 key globally on laptop with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

**How to Disable F5 key Globally**

I want my F5 key to do absolutely nothing. I am on Ubuntu 20.04 installed on laptop.

I have tried this but it only works inside terminal

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 71 ='
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to run your command when logging in. That appears to have its caveat's, though (see [2nd answer by jimm-cl here](https://superuser.com/questions/775785/how-to-disable-a-keyboard-key-in-linux-ubuntu)). When executed in a terminal, it only takes effect in your current shell. It may be preferred to use the command `xmodmap -e 'keycode 71=NoSymbol'`

A very simple approach to disable a key in the desktop environment is to set a custom shortcut for <kbd>F5</kbd> in "Keyboard Shortcuts" that does nothing. These shortcuts take precedence over the ones defined in an application.

In the "Keyboard Shortcuts" dialog, Click <kbd>+</kbd> at the bottom to add a shortcut:

- Name: "Disable F5"
- Command:  echo
- Shortcut: indicate F5.

Comment: Thank you so much. I added f5 key as a shortcut like you said and it solved my issue.

Comment: It is how I disable `Ctrl+q` to prevent accidentally being thrown out of the browser while all I wanted was to close a tab (`Ctrl+w`). Glad this was of help.